# Android Is using Application Class as a contoller OK?

Tags: android, oop, architecture

I would like to have all my Activities (7 to 10 different screens) submit data to a "controller" (sorry if I'm miss using the term).

Inside said controller data would either be uploaded or saved to data for uploading when no internet.
The controller would do checks and processing such as:

- Checking for valid session.
- Attach other needed credentials before
  upload etc.
  Session/User data would be stored in a Shared Preferences file the controller has reference to.

My goal is to have Activities do nothing more than collect the data and call the appropriate method (with a data object) asynchronously.  The controller would know how to process the data for uploading or saving in the database.

Would placing these methods in an extension of Application be a bad idea?

> It was mentioned that depending on application size this is feasable, but there could be better solutions.

Comment: I would recommend using an `IntentService` to perform uploading and use a `BroadcastReceiver` to 'listen' for network changes. How and where you store pending uploads will depend on the type and amount of data to be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your project, that would be a suitable idea. However, there are some other ways you should know before choosing the method you're actually implementing:

- Using a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for your data, an [`AccountAuthenticator`](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html) and then sync to the server using an [`SyncAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). Advantages are a good abstraction, independence from activities and many built-in features (for example: Android executes your code without a big battery life impact). However, implementing all the stuff is quite much work at first. If you don't want to use the `ContentProvider`, the same technique works with a [stub implementation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-stub-provider.html) as well, the same goes for the `AccountAuthenticator`.
- Using a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), probably [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), for your uploading needs. Advantage is that the Service has an independent lifecicle and thus is not directly related to your Activity; a Service can get restarted if it has been killed by the system. Still more work than just using some static methods.
- Using a static method as you're proposing it (in your case, the Application object; not completely static, but compareable). Quite easy to implement, probably the best way if there are similar tasks in multiple activities; your [`AsyncTask`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) can send their result directly to the activitiy that started it. However not suitable for long-running tasks.
- Implementing within the Activity; If code is only used once; listed for completeness only, not for your case. Basically the same as using a static method.

These are the ones that popped into my mind, there might be some others, too. Feel free to add/suggest additonal ones.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it addressed my main concern.  "Is this a bad idea."  However you did bring up some quite good solutions.  I wonder if I might ask a few follow-up questions.  I'll add them to my original post.

Comment: @user2484014 comment here or @-mention me once your questions are up

Comment: Where are my manners?...  Thank you so much for your detailed response.   I think I want to go with an IntentService since it will suite the end goal well.  I think I'm just getting hung up, because our web service is a bit quirky.  I don't just send a command and data object.  Some of the data I pass is part of the command... /sigh .net folk (just kidding).  Anyways somehow I'm just being over-concerned about the 2-3 calls that are different rater than the 5-6 that are all the same.  In any case it's time for me to do some reading.  Thanks again for your time.